# SQL - No Sales in given last x Years

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to run a query that finds the customers who have not purchased anything in the last x years. I'm not sure of whether to use a loop, or use the BETWEEN key word.

If you need to see the tables please let me know, thanks.

```
-- Find out the information of the customers who have not purchased anything in the 
--last couple of years. Give the number of years (e.g., 1,2,3,4).

create procedure purchaseYear(@year int)
AS

select *
from customer
where CID IN(
select CID from item 
where ItemNum IN (
select ItemNum from sale
where year(Comp_Date) =  Between year(getdate()) AND @year))
```

Comment: how do you identify a customer purchase?

Comment: Add the structure of your tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this

```
Declare @Year int = 7

Select A.*
 From  Customer A
 Join (Select CID
        From  Item
        Group By CID
        Having max(Comp_Date)<=DateAdd(YY,-@Year,cast(GetDate() as date))
      ) B
   on A.CID=B.CID
```

Answer (score 0):

See if this works.

```
SELECT d.cid,
       year(getdate())-year(lastDate) as years
FROM
  ( SELECT c.cid,
           max(s.comp_date) AS lastDate
   FROM sale s
   INNER JOIN item i ON s.itemnum = i.itemnum
   INNER JOIN customer c ON c.cid = i.cid
   GROUP BY c.cid
   UNION SELECT c.cid,
                max(NULL) AS lastDate
   FROM customer c
   LEFT OUTER JOIN item i ON c.cid = i.cid
   WHERE i.cid IS NULL
   GROUP BY c.cid ) d
```

Answer (score 0):

If you rephrase the question as "I want to find companies whose most recent purchase is more than x years ago" the answer should be clear.

```
; with companyAndLastPurchaseAge as (
   Select companyId, max(DateDiff(y, saledate, getdate())) YearsAgo
   From sale
   Group by companyId
 )
 select cid.*
 From cid 
     Left join companyAndLastPurchaseYear cp
         On cp.CompanyId = cid.companyId and yearsago < x
 Where cp.companyid is null;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    create procedure purchaseYear(@year int)
    AS


    select *
    from customer as c 
    where not exists(
        Select item.CID from sale
        inner join item on item.ItemNum=sale.ItemNum
        where item.CID=c.CID and datediff(year,Comp_Date,GETDATE())  Between 0 AND @year 
    )
```